# How to enable multithreading in Clion?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have written a simple code to test `threading` in `C++11`. But I can't run it in `Clion IDE`, it gives following error in red lines.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
```

Process finishes with exit code `134`.

some details about my system :

- linux ubuntu 14.10
- C++11

I guess the code is not that important to solve this problem, but I am pasting it here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void task1 () {
    cout << "Task 1::"<<endl;
}

int main() {
    thread t1(task1);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to specify C++11 or latet?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it is C++11. Thank you @kometen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `CMakeList.txt` file of my project, I just added one command `-pthread` to the the following line

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

So that looks like

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")
```

It solves the problem.